# SQL Server 2008R2 database is offline, and transact log file is full

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

My database has filled the drive with the transaction log, its about 15GB and the drive is now full.  The database won't start.  The database is currently offline.

I can access SQL Server Management Studio, but not sure what to do next to fix up the transaction log, and get the database back on line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would appear to have the database set to use the Full recovery model.

The log is supposed to be truncated when the database is backed up using a backup tool that integrates with SQL Server (at that point you have a snapshot of the DB at that point in time for recovery), but if you don't have an appropriate regular backup in place, the log tends to bloat out to fill the available disk space.

If you don't require the full recovery model, then change to the Simple Recovery model (right-click on the database node in SSMS, select Properties and go to the Options page) and then shrink the DB.

Comment: I do have daily backups in place.  But this log grew during one afternoon when I was manually inserting a new large dataset and my insert code had a bug which caused it to loop without end until the log filled.

I go to the database in SSMS, right-click, go to Properties, there is no options page.  The database is offline.